# Yahoo Finance - How to get companies Key Statistics

Tags: yahoo-finance

I have used codeproject to get share data from yahoo
( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37550/Stock-quote-and-chart-from-Yahoo-in-C ).

In yahoo finance, there are 'Key Statistics' which i would like to use, but are not available by this means (e.g. data at http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=BNZL.L ). Is there any way to get this information directly? I would really rather not screen scrape if possible.

I am using C#/.NET4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my lib for .NET [Yahoo! Managed](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/). There you have the MaasOne.Finance.YahooFinance.CompanyStatisticsDownload class to do exactly what you want.

p/s: You need to use the latest version (0.10.1). v0.10.0.2 is obsolete with Key Statistics Download.

Comment: That is an absolute GEM of an answer. Thank you! I had tried the old version of Yahoo! Managed (from CodeProject - [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42575/Yahoo-Finance-Managed)), in which all the answers in the test app come out as zero or N/A. The link you gave works perfectly. Sorry to bother you again, but do you know if the methods often need to be upversioned? No worries if you are busy. I am really pleased to be able to get at the information for now.

Comment: Not very often. These statisitcs data are not part of the official CSV-API of yahoo. Instead the lib parses the normal yahoo page (via YQL; so the end data are from official API ^^; that's important because licensing). So, every time yahoo changes its site (the table parts), the lib needs an update. greetz

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the info. I will donate to the project when i have been paid, as it is really good!

Comment: Just donated. Sorry it's not much. If i ever start making money, i'll send more your way.

Answer (score 4):

I landed on this question while searching for an answer couple of days ago, thought of providing an answer I created in R (and shared it on R-Bloggers). I know that the answer I am providing is not in C# but XPath and XML are supported in every language so you can use this approach there.  The URL to the blog is - http://www.r-bloggers.com/pull-yahoo-finance-key-statistics-instantaneously-using-xml-and-xpath-in-r/

```
#######################################################################
##Alternate method to download all key stats using XML and x_path - PREFERRED WAY
#######################################################################

setwd("C:/Users/i827456/Pictures/Blog/Oct-25")
require(XML)
require(plyr)
getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
   measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

   #Clean up the column name
   measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

   #Remove dups
   dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
   #print(dups) 
   for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
     measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

   #use siblings function to get value
   values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

   df <- data.frame(t(values))
   colnames(df) <- measures
   return(df)
  } else {
    break
  }
}

tickers <- c("AAPL")
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)  

#######################################################################
```

Comment: That is screen scraping, it's slow and consumes more data

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the key statistics from BarChart.com, here is a simple function script:

```
library(XML)

getKeyStats <- function(symbol) {
  barchart.URL <- "http://www.barchart.com/profile.php?sym="
  barchart.URL.Suffix <- "&view=key_statistics"
  html_table <- readHTMLTable(paste(barchart.URL, symbol, barchart.URL.Suffix, sep = ""))
  df_keystats = html_table[[5]]
  print(df_keystats)
 }
```

Comment: This site doesn't seem to have stocks on the London Stock Exchange, but definitely looks to have some relevant info on US stocks. Thanks.